# Jackson deserialize message

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I send wrong JSON:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)   
public ResponseEntity<?> requestParseException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
    String errMessage = messageService.getMessage(INVALID_JSON_DATA);
    return ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST)
        .body(new BadRequestException(errMessage).toString());   
}
```

I have such message:

> Can not deserialize value of type int from String "asd": not a valid Integer value

How I can change such message

For example

> Error in node: "Test". String "asd" can't be parse  Integer value

Comment: Why you do not  catch this message at runtime and throw a meaningful message as you implied instead ?

Comment: Can you give small example

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Is user seeing this error?

Comment: Yes. I want send this message for user. So that he knows where he does not have the right json